# Cell with an image in CSS grid takes up too much space

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid

I'm trying to create a 3 column layout where:

- left and right colums are equal in width
- left colum is empty
- right column contains the image caption (a text of arbitrary length)
- middle column contains an image. Image should have the height of 100% (fill the viewport vertically).
- no layout shifts happen when the image loads (I included `width` and `height` attributes on the image).
- I intend to use it with `srcset` and `<picture>` (too serve correct image sizes and jpeg/webp). I did not include this in the demo.

Here's my attempt:

```css
body, figure {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

figure {
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  
  border: 2px solid red;
}

figure::before {
  content: 'abc';
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<figure>  
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/600" width="400" height="600" alt="cat">
  <figcaption>This is a cat</figcaption>
</figure>
```

This is how it looks like (screenshot shows grid tracks from Firefox dev tools):

[image: unnecessary space around the image]

The issue is this space I painted with red pen over. It makes the grid cell with the image too wide. I want this to look like this:

[image: desired result - no space around the image]

Here the grid cell is only as wide as it needs to in order to fit the image (preserving aspect ratio). As a result the image is centered horizontally.

How do I do that?

Comment: you will get surprised to see the output on chrome

Comment: Haha, yeah. Well, I guess I'll see if I get a correct answer and whether it looks good in Chrome. Cheers for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, try to avoid making images into grid or flex items. There are still too many bugs in modern browsers that prevent reliable rendering.

I just wrote about this here: [How can I get an image to fit to the size of a grid cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61227209/3597276)

That said, here's a solution you may find useful:

```css
body,
figure {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

figure {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr min-content 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

figure::before {
  content: 'abc';
}

div {
  min-height: 0;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/600" width="400" height="600" alt="cat">
  </div>
  <figcaption>This is a cat</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: yes but you fixed the height to 100vh, I guess he want the element to be at max 100vh and less if the image is smaller (not sure if it's possible btw)

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that the image will be the highest element you can move the `max-height:100vh` to it and it will be easier:

```css
body, figure {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

figure {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  
  border: 2px solid red;
}

figure::before {
  content: 'abc';
}

img {
  max-height:calc(100vh - 4px); /* considering the border */
  width: auto;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<figure>  
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/600" width="400" height="600" alt="cat">
  <figcaption>This is a cat</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score -1):

try to put justify-content:center in the figure. and the max-width:100% in the img.
this is what will center the image horizontally in the figure and makes it to take the full with.

Comment: No, it didn't work. And putting `max-width: 100%` on the image made it disappear... ;)

Answer (score -2):

A few changes I would make ;)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

figure {
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(50%, min-content) 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

figure::before {
  content: 'abc';
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/600" width="400" height="600" alt="cat">
  <figcaption>This is a cat</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: It's close, but it doesn't suit my needs unfortunately. On larger screens the image won't have a height of 100%. I need the image to fill the available space vertically.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the image doesn't actually fill the screen verticallty. Even when I added `height:100%` to the `<figure>`.

Comment: The photo fills 100% of the figure's height. If you add figure height 100% then the figure will be full screen and img vertically centered.

Comment: Correct. I need the figure to be 100% tall too. Sorry if I didn't make it clear upfront.

Comment: In the example I added `height:100%` to figure

Comment: So click "Run code snippet" and then "Full page". Assuming you're using a desktop-size monitor, you'll see the image is small, doesn't fill the viewport height.